# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

i keep getting this error

> **Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not
>   exist: hdfs:/filename.txt**

I have set up a standalone spark cluster and i am trying to run this code on my master node.

```
conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Recommendation Engine1")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
      .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rawUserArtistData = sc.textFile("hdfs:/user_artist_data.txt").sample(false,0.05)
```

on my terminal i run,

> *spark-submit --class com.latentview.spark.Reco  --master spark://MASTERNODE U IP:PORT   --deploy-mode client
>   /home/cloudera/workspace/new/Sparksample/target/Sparksample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar*

These are the various things that i tried,

1. I replaced the hdfs:/filename.txt with fs.defaultFS path which was present on my core-site.xml file
2. Replaced the hdfs:/filename.txt with hdfs:// (if at all it makes any difference)
3. Replaced the hdfs:/ with file:// and later with file:/// to access my local drive for the files

None of this seems to work is there anything else that could be going wrong.

if i do hadoop fs -ls

[image]

this is where my files are.

Comment: what do you get when you run `hadoop fs -ls hdfs:/user_artist_data.txt`? If nothing or error then would you please let us know the path of user_artist_data.txt after finding it thru `hadoop fs -ls` command?

Comment: @abhiieor please refer my edit i have added the screen shot of the location

Comment: So if you have `user_artist_data .txt` there then the path should be something like `/user/<userName>/user_artist_data.txt`. To find out do `hadoop fs -ls /user` and one of the hadoop dir that you can recognize as user will be there (I expect just one dir as output)

Comment: my path is /user/cloudera/user_artist_data.txt yes i have tried to replace hdfs:/user/cloudera/user_artist_data.txt and it still doesn't work @abhiieor

Comment: File does not exist: /user/cloudera/artist_alias.txt get again :( @abhiieor

Comment: try just `val rawUserArtistData = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/user_artist_data.txt").sample(false,0.05)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121892/discussion-between-user2860954-and-abhiieor).

Comment: very sorry I am replying from office. Though allowed to answer ques in SO but chat is blocked :(

Comment: Okay i keep getting the same error. And it is "org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): File does not exist: /user/cloudera/artist_alias.txt"

Comment: Have you started your HDFS ? I mean there is a shell script that starts the dfs, check if its running. If that is already started then are you able to access this file through web-browser HDFS interface. If both of these are okay, then your URL should be hdfs://<<yourhost>>:8020/remaining file path, per my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the path is:

`hdfs://name-nodeIP:8020/path/to/file`

In your case it must be,

`hdfs://localhost:8020/user_artist_data.txt`

or

`hdfs://machinname:8020/user_artist_data.txt`

Answer (score 0):

the org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException error mean that spark can not create RDD because the folder "hdfs:/user_artist_data.txt" has no file on it.
try to connect hdfs://localhost:8020/user_artist_data.txt and see if there are any files.